# Using Applescript/Automator to enable Mouse Keys on Mac

Tags: mac, keyboard, mouse, applescript

I am trying to use applescript and automator to temporarily disable the trackpad while a program loads onto a Mac Air running Sierra. I have parental controls set on the account that runs the software preventing the user from accessing the System Preferences. Therefore, I want to either use Applescript to "tap" the option key five times to Enable Mouse Keys OR temporarily by-pass the parental controls to allow the account to access the parental controls while it enables the mouse keys. I've provided the scripting I've tried.

The following scripts don't work for me:

```
tell application "System Events" to key code 96 using {option down, command down} 

Tell application "System Events"
    repeat 5 times
        key down option
        key up option
    end repeat
end tell
```

The following script does work, but would require me to temporarily by-pass the parental controls:

```
tell application "System Preferences"
        reveal anchor "Mouse" of pane id "com.apple.preference.universalaccess"
        activate
        delay 0.1
        tell application "System Events"
            tell process "System Preferences"
                click checkbox "Enable Mouse Keys" of window "Accessibility"
            end tell
        end tell
        quit
end tell
```

Any ideas or help would be appreciated!

Comment: I'm also willing to use terminal. I was able to unload the kext file, but when I reload it, it causes the system to restart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In my keyboard/ accessibility/ shortcuts - system preferences… I
   changed my default keyboard shortcut to show accessibility controls
   to “option key + 4” as you can see in this next image

---

[image]

2. Then in my accessibility preferences, I selected the option to show
   accessibility status in the menu bar

---

[image]

---

3. Running this following AppleScript will display the accessibility
   options menu and toggle the “Enable Mouse Keys” option.

---

```
tell application "System Events"
    set volume with output muted
    delay 0.7
    key code 21 using option down
    delay 1
    repeat 4 times
        delay 1
        key code 48
    end repeat
    delay 1
    key code 49
    key code 36
    delay 1
    set volume without output muted
end tell
```

[image]

[image]

This works for me in the latest version of Sierra.  I do not have parental controls enabled on my system so I'm not sure if this will work for you or not

Comment: Perfect! I had tried earlier to key code 96 using {option down, command down}, but didn't work. Your solution worked EXACTLY as I needed on the user account with parental permissions set. No issues!

Comment: I added two lines of code to mute and un mute the volume because the voiceover was annoying as it was scrolling